# image analysis and detecting unanalyzed areas

Tags: image, canvas, analysis

So here's a problem and question:

I'm analyzing a document page on HTML5 Canvas and detecting certain features, such as boxes, labels, text blocks, images, tables, etc. Because Canvas is slow for pixel read/write and the image needs to be high-res for good accuracy e.g.: 1500 x 2500, I cannot afford to analyze every pixel, let alone in multiple passes.

My algorithm does some random pixel pokes and does some minimal analysis to find if there is a usable bounding box for further processing and the type of processing that needs to be done; some parts may be sent to the server, like OCR.

Every subsequent random poke checks against a growing list of successfully found bounding boxes and pokes elsewhere until it gets into uncharted waters. The technique is surprisingly simple and effective, but this results in a lot of extra random pokes and does not provide consistent results without large poke counts (1% of area), and even then it misses some parts intermittently.

What would be great is to implement some spatial analysis algorithm that can tell me where the unpoked areas are outside of all bounding boxes, so that I can restrict my x/y random coordinate selection to there only. It should increase the efficacy and speed by a significant amount.

My typical box count for a fully analyzed doc page is < 200.

Does any algorithm exist in the public domain/wiki that can do this in JavaScript reasonably fast?

Comment: Canvas isn't slow for pixel read/write, as you simply have to work on the data obtained via getImageData.

Comment: 1500 * 2500 = 3.75 million px * 4 subpixels = 15 million element CanvasPixelArray. I would love to see how you iterate the entire thing "quickly" in js. For me, "quickly" means having the full page analysis completed in < 1500 ms. It goes without saying that I've been using getImageData, what else is there?

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts that I hope might help. A broad idea it still needs some work!

Assumptions are that no bounding boxes overlap and are found one at a time.

The following would turned into a recursive procedure 'Check' on documents which halts when documents are too small to continue.

Check (document)

If (document is root document) {

Find a bounding box in document

Split document horizontally into 4 new documents

for each new document Check ( new document)

}

else {

Find a bounding box in document

if (bounding box wholly inside document) {

Split document horizontally into 4 new documents

for each new document Check ( new document)

}

else {

Split parent document into 4 vertically

Using information found about position of bounding box

Check (appropriate vertical document)

for each of other vertical documents check(document)

}

The following is a pdf file to help illustrate the idea.

[Bounding Boxes](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxqa2dhZGdldHN0b3JlfGd4OjE1NGRmNjc5OWRkNDhiY2E&pli=1)

Comment: that's a neat idea, actually. thanks for the detailed drawings. the problem with this method that i see is how would you know if a block of text at the edge of one sectioned document is cut off or whole? text blocks don't really have "bounds" per-se...you would have to rely on some minimum whitespace to the edge, which is fine. another issue is with form fields which can be staggered like bricks and often are not 100% enclosed in bounding lines when they are at the page edges, making it hard to detect. i will give this some thought, thanks.

Comment: @leeonia More thoughts. Suppose you have a document, D, with edges xl,xr,yt,yb with xl<xr, yt<yb and yt not 0. You find a bounding box at the top edge x0,x1,yt,y1 with x0<x1 and yt<y1 would it be possible to restrict your next document search to the document with edges x0,x1,y2,yt where y2<yt and y2>y3 where y3 is at the top edge of the document just above the document D. This way it could be possible to find the upper section of a 'cut off' block or a blank if none found. A second check using the vertical slicing might then confirm?